# Missing artifact error for provided scope dependecy in maven 3.1.0

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management, artifact, build-tools

I have a dependency with scope provided in `pom.xml` file. But m2e give *Missing artifact* error

```
<dependency>  
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>  
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>  
   <version>11.2.0.3</version>  
   <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>`
```

Why is it so ? I have 4 more dependencies with `provided` scope all are having same error.

Comment: Do you have `ojdbc6` in local repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ojdbc6` is not available in maven repository, install it locally. This is required even if with scope `provided`.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

More: [How To Add Oracle JDBC Driver In Your Maven Local Repository](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

As MariuszS already mentioned an other alterative would be to use a [repository manag](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)er and install it there.